# How to shrink the size of a div / section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to shrink the size of a div / section, such as resizing the image into small ....

[image: image description]

NOTE: DIV SECTION not Image,.. thanks

Comment: Can you provide me the JSFiddle for the same!

Comment: post your code to try with that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shrink div & make image smaller then as per my suggestion use Bootstrap for perfect shrink image & There css class code is also very simple.

There you can use "image-responsive"class also for handle size of image

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make above structure in bootstrap then,

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='col-md-12'>
<!--Left part-->
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='row' style='height:80%'>
            <image class="img responsive" src='' height='100%' width='100%'>  
        </div> 
        <div class='row' style='height:20%'>
            <div class='col-md-2'><image class="img responsive" src='' id='img1' /></div>
            <div class='col-md-2'><image class="img responsive" src='' id='img2'/></div>
            <div class='col-md-2'><image class="img responsive" src='' id='img3'/></div>
            <div class='col-md-2'><image class="img responsive" src='' id='img4'/></div>
            <div class='col-md-2'><image class="img responsive" src='' id='img5'/></div>
        </div>
    </div><!--Right part-->
    <div class='col-md-6'> Put your code </div></div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use css3's scale attribute.

```
.class {
-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);
-moz-transform:scale(0.5);
-ms-transform:scale(0.5);
transform:scale(0.5);
}
```

Comment: does it not? I don't see why it wouldn't.